# Docker Base Images and Scaling Architecture

Tags: docker

I have an app running on MongoDB, Node JS Api, React front end, Nginx proxy, etc. I have all of these setup as individual images and running locally (OSX) in separate linked containers, which I run with Docker Compose. In production, I have setup a (one) Ubuntu server on Digital Ocean at the moment, and expect to quickly scale as needed to multiple servers.

My question is what is the best way to handle the underlying Linux base image for each of these containers?

1) Should all of the linux setup (apt-gets, node / mongo installs, etc) exist on the Linux machine and outside of Docker and one could simply create a snapshot of this image, spin up a new server instance, and run the desired Docker container if you needed to quickly scale, or

2) Should all of the linux setup exist within a 'base' Ubuntu image, which the mongo, node, and nginx images build on top of. This results in each image's size growing significantly since they each have a separate instance of Ubuntu, plus all of the package dependencies to run mongo, node, and nginx, or

3) Should each process (mongo, node, nginx) have a separate linux base Docker image since they each have separate dependencies? Again, each image would be grow because they each would run an instance of Ubuntu.

What is the proper way to handle this with Docker?

Comment: Docker pulls in layers individually, so the size of your image shouldn't be affected by a base image.

Comment: So is #2 above the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is #2, but I suspect you may not fully understand the relationship between container and image.

### How Docker uses images

First of all an image from the the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/understanding-docker/):

[image]

Containers are created from images. An image is only downloaded and cached locally. Images are distributed via Registries.

### Image layers

What makes Docker images different from virtual machine images is how they're built and stored. Again from the docs:

> Each image consists of a series of layers. 
>   Docker makes use of union file systems to combine these
>   layers into a single image. Union file systems allow files and
>   directories of separate file systems, known as branches, to be
>   transparently overlaid, forming a single coherent file system.
>
> One of the reasons Docker is so lightweight is because of these
>   layers. When you change a Docker image—for example, update an
>   application to a new version— a new layer gets built. Thus, rather
>   than replacing the whole image or entirely rebuilding, as you may do
>   with a virtual machine, only that layer is added or updated. Now you
>   don’t need to distribute a whole new image, just the update, making
>   distributing Docker images faster and simpler.

So, your mongo, node, and nginx images will be thin layers on top of a base image containing your basic Linux setup. That base image will only be downloaded once and will be re-used as a component layer by the other images.